# Loading and unloading fonts for multilingual Flex app

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, fonts

My Flex app allows people to enter text. There's a broad selection of fonts to choose from. Because it is a multi-lingual app, some of those fonts (e.g. Chinese) are very large indeed - too big to embed all fonts.

I know that I can [load fonts at runtime via stylesheets](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_10.html) - I plan to do this as people select a font (a small wait while the font loads is not a problem). What I want to be able to do is to *unload* those fonts again, so that the app doesn't consume huge amount of memory if people select one font and then another.

I can't see a way to do it, though. I can load fonts at runtime, but not unload them. Any ideas?

I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812999/adobe-flex-loading-embedded-fonts-from-modules) on SO that mentions loading fonts as part of a module - with one font per module, I guess. The advantage being that modules can be unloaded. But then, the font isn't accessible outside the module, as the questioner points out. So that seems like a dead end.

If it's not possible, I  will - sadly - accept an answer that shows me that it's impossible, but much more useful would be an alternative strategy! This must be a pretty common scenario that people have run into before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your intuition suggests, this is a relatively common scenario for flex developers - there's got to be a solution!

As you have suggested, I would compile the stylesheets as modules with the fonts embedded in each (for Chinese, I suggest you look at specifying unicode ranges if possible to save on font size: http://renaun.com/blog/2011/10/flash-embed-font-unicode-range-generator/).

There are 3 application domains you can load modules into a parent app.  Take a look at this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e07.html.  I believe 2 out of the 3 ways allows you to use resources from the module.  The easiest is to load it with the same application domain - meaning you assume the classes in the module are the same as the parent's.

Make sure your build system is compiling the modules with the same version of the sdk as the parent application.  Otherwise, you will run into actionscript runtime errors with marshalling classes.

Finally, how are you profiling your application for garbage collection?  Are you using the flash builder's built-in profiler?  Forcing garbage collection on a flex app is annoying (from what I remember, you must call `System.gc()` twice or some weird voodoo magic like that).

Comment: Ah I didn't realise that about loading modules with a specific application domain. No-one's really answered this, but yours has been most helpful so you get the bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some useful links:

- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_04.html (esp. see the section beginning "Embedding fonts in ActionScript")
- http://divillysausages.com/blog/as3_font_embedding_masterclass
- http://bryanlangdon.com/blog/2007/03/22/loading-fonts-dynamically-in-actionscript-2-and-3/

You can embed the fonts externally in SWF files (one per font), load them up as needed, and use the same value as SWF Embed's "fontName" for CSS's "fontFamily".

When the user is done, and you've cleared all references to the font, you can unload the SWF (Loader.unloadAndStop()) and set it to null. I would think this would prompt it for garbage collection and free up the memory.

I think this is your best bet, because for a font to be used it must be registered, no matter how you got it to that point. And there is no Font.unregisterFont() method. This solution at least lets you free up everything up to that point.

Though I'm curious if Font.enumerateFonts() would still list the font and if it is really freed for garbage collection...

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that, and if you've registered the font, it won't get GC'd, even if there are no other references.

Comment: If only there *was* a Font.unregisterFont() method! That would be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got too deep into it, but I too think it's not possible to unload a registered font.

I can only think of two probably unfeasible workarounds:

- Come up with an elaborate and reliable way to use device fonts. I
  guess it would imply quite an extensive investigation about fonts
  available/required in different systems and countries, but if you're
  not using the font for very graphical things, I think it could be
  pulled off.
- Reload the whole movie when you change the font. This
  obviously depends heavily in what's your application like, but maybe
  you could save the app state and reload it through javascript, or
  maybe even have a separate overlaid swf that you load on demand
  (maybe the latter could work loading the swf in a separate
  application/security domain, but I'm not sure the registered fonts
  would be sandboxed correctly).

Anyway, I guess it being a Flex app would complicate things quite a bit and render anything outside the box useless...